# Is PE 1.10.0.4 beta the same thing as PC 1.13.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, version-differences

Is the latest version of Minecraft PE the same as 1.13.2 in Minecraft PC edition? I have a friend that wants me to build him a map and I want to know his version but I don't really know how to determine what version to use to make a map.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, 1.10.0.4 beta in Bedrock Edition is not the same as 1.13.2 in PC Edition.

[Bedrock Edition 1.10](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.10.0) released some of the features of the Village and Pillage update, including wandering traders, composters, and pillager outposts. Versions [1.8.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.8.0) and [1.9.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.9.0) also added certain features of Village and Pillage.

[PC version 1.13](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.13) was Update Aquatic, and it added things like fish mobs, phantoms, and tridents. It is roughly equivalent to [Bedrock 1.6.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.6.0).

[PC edition 1.10](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.10) was the Frostburn Update, released way back in 2016. It added several new features including polar bears, magma blocks, and husks.

1.13.2 for PC does not include any features of Village and Pillage, whereas 1.10 for Bedrock does.

Comment: soooo... what version is 1.10.0.4 in minecraft pc? is it the latest snapshot?

Comment: @Zed no, 1.10 for PC was actually the Frostburn Update, released in 2016. It added things like polar bears, strays, and fossils.

Comment: Way more importantly than the arguments listed here: MCJava and MCBE are entirely separate games. No version is the same as any version of the other game.

Answer (score -1):

no. the Java Edition equivalent to PE 1.10.0.4 beta would be 1.14 Pre-Release 2.